# Open modal JFace Dialog on top of another modal JFace Dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, modal-dialog, jface

I have a custom JFace Dialog (called PropertyDialog) which extends the FormDialog. I would like to open a modal Message Dialog over the PropertryDialog as soon as it opens, to display a message to the user.

How could this be accomplished? Would I have to override the `open()` method? Note that it is required that the `PropertyDialog.open()` does not return until a button is pressed on the button bar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use `TitleAreaDialog` which has space for an error message at the top of the dialog so you don't need another dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately, I do not have control over the type which the Properties Dialog extends, since it doesn't extends it directly but through a series of other Classes which provide some extra functionality.
Also, it already extends `FormDialog` in this chain of hierarchy, so changing it to `TitleAreaDialog` would not be possible. Hence, I want to open a `MessageDialog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by displaying the message at the end of the `createContents` method, like this:

```
  @Override
  protected Control createContents(final Composite parent)
  {
    final Control control = super.createContents(parent);

    parent.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
      public void run()
      {
        MessageDialog.openInformation(getShell(), "title", "message");
      }
    });

    return control;
  }
```

You need to use `Display.asyncExec` so that the dialog is not displayed until the parent dialog has been displayed.

Comment: Awesome Reply! I never knew that! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank You very much for your help!